# Выслать объект json на url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Задача: выслать данные в *json* на *www.example.ru*

Пробую сделать следущим образом.
Создал *html* c кодом:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    var JsonData = {"name":"Luc","xxxx":"yyy"};

$.getJSON("example.ru?callback=?",  
{request:$.toJSON(JsonData)}, 
function(data) {
    console.log(data.request); 
    });    
</script>
```

Смысл задания - в получении ключа *API*.

Comment: Используйте post, а не get

Comment: тоже об этом подумал, поменял на POST, далее запустил index.html с кодом в браузере (уверен что надо как то по другому) и ни чего не произошло.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте элементарный ajax-запрос

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'example.ru',
   type: 'get',
   data: JsonData,
   success: function( data ) {
        // Полученная от сервера информация в переменной data
   }
});
```

Подробно можно прочитать [здесь](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать, но через что или как его высылать? терминал, консоль в браузере, извените если глупый вопрос, но ни как не могу найти ответа!

Comment: @Лука если вы вставите этот код на страницу тогда запрос будет отправлятся при загрузке страницы.  Вы можете привязать его к каому-либо действию, например клик по кнопке, либо отправка формы.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел отличное решение, может кому пригодится c терминала:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/api/login
```